# Where can I/should I place files outside my home directory?

Tags: permissions, directory-structure, non-root-user

I'm using a Linux system on which I don't have root. My home directory is remote-mounted and backed up (and there's a quota on that filesystem). Now, I would like to work on some files on this machine itself, they don't need to be backed up, and I would like to (but not have to) have them relatively large.

Where can I put these files? Where can I create a folder of my own outside my own home directory?

Notes:

- Under `/tmp` is not a solution, the files need to persist.
- It's a Fedora 20, but if you have a Debian'ish answer that's interesting as well.
- The local filesystems don't have a quota.

Comment: Sometimes I see files placed in `/usr/local/bin`..

Comment: @ryekayo: Its permissions are `drwxr-xr-x.`, so I can't put anything there.

Comment: `/var/tmp`. Like `/tmp` but persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `/var/tmp`, but:

If you have a quota, the admin will probably not appreciate you creating large files outside of your `$HOME` directory. Quite likely you even got a limit for `/var/tmp`. So that might just be an option for small files.

However, if you are member of the `fuse` group (ask your admin to add you to the group if you're not), you can use `sshfs` and mount a remote file system of arbitrary size.

Example:

```
sshfs <user@host:directory> <mountpoint>
```

Comment: `/var/tmp` is on the desktop itself, so no quota.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases as an admin I set aside `/usr/local` for my users to use for files that they for whatever reason don't want to, or cant use their `$HOME` directory for it.

At the end of the day though:  **This sounds like a job for a conversation between you and your sysadmin**

Realistically it is probably intended that you work within the confines of `$HOME` quota's and all, but generally speaking a quick conversation about what you want, and a 5 seconds of effort on a sysadmin's part can yield you a private directory somewhere intended for you to work your magic.